# Remove Duplicates from LinkedList without using HashSet - Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am attempting to remove a student from the linked list if the two students are the same, meaning a duplicate input. This is being tested with JUnit test cases. However, any testing is returning the same list with no students removed. This is the removeDuplicate method, where list is my linkedList.

```
public void removeDuplicates() {

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))) {
                list.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of one of the failing test cases:

```
public void test_removeDuplicates_1() {
    ISimpleDatabase model = new SimpleDatabaseModel();
    Student s1 = new Student("John Doe", "G123456789", 3.5);
    Student s2 = new Student("Paul Graham", "G123456987", 2.75);
    Student s3 = new Student("Mary Joe", "G331456987", 3.25);
    Student s4 = new Student("Martin Fowler", "G654789321", 3.65);
    Student s5 = new Student("Paul Graham", "G123456987", 2.75);
    Student s6 = new Student("Mary Joe", "G331456987", 3.25);
    model.insert(s1);
    model.insert(s2);
    model.insert(s3);
    model.insert(s4);
    model.insert(s5);
    model.insert(s6);
    model.removeDuplicates();
    String expected = s1 + "\n" + s2 + "\n" + s3 + "\n" + s4;
    assertEquals(expected,model.toString().trim());
```

Which returns this error:

[image: test case failure]

I am certain the error is in the removeDuplicates() method, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You clearly are being over-eager to not exceed the index bounds (as you are using a strict comparison, the bound should be `list.size() - 1` in the outer loop and `list.size()` in the inner loop). That'd explain why Mary Joe doesn't get removed, but does not explain why Paul Graham stays as well.

Comment: I tried that first, but wondered if that was causing the problems, so then I changed it. I have since changed it back, but you are correct in thinking it doesn't fix any of the errors. I've been looking at this too long and I think I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: I've spotted another error (which still can't be the cause of the problem here): If you call `remove(j)`, the indices of all remaining elements get shifted by -1. Thus, you'd have to write `remove(j--)` to counteract the increment of `j` at the end of the loop body.
What about the `equals` method of your `Student` class?

Comment: @TABmayfield, can you share your Student class? At least the overriden version of the equals method? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've added the student class with the equals method.

Comment: I've modified the method to check just the GNumber(student id) and used a while loop instead and now it's passing all of the test cases.  Apparently I just needed some time away from the problem. Your help with the added bits of logic really helped. Thanks guys!

Comment: You didn't actually add the student class, which we still need. (And I'm betting that you *only* overrode equals.)

Comment: I added it, but then edited it because there was so much code and I've already figured out a solution, which I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove an item you need to step `j` back one so you test the newly shuffled-down item, otherwise you will miss it.

```
if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))) {
    list.remove(j);
    j--;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out something that works. I'm just checking one of the fields for duplicates because if the student id is the same, then the student is the same as well. This appears to pass all test cases now for me. Just needed some time away to figure it out. Thanks everyone.

```
public void removeDuplicates() {

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        int count = i + 1;
        while (count < list.size()) {
            if (list.get(i).getGnumber().equals(list.get(count).getGnumber())) {
                list.remove(count);
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```